# SQL - Select all rows and count only column greater than 1

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have this table:

```
name| value
----|------
 A  | 0
 B  | 0
 A  | 1 
 C  | 1
 A  | 1
```

The select I want is to give the result like this:

```
A | 2
B | 0
C | 1
```

In first phase I tried with:

```
SELECT name, count(0)
FROM table
WHERE value > 0
GROUP BY name;
```

Which result

```
A | 2
C | 1
```

I also want to include `B` with `count(0) = 0`. How I can do this?

Comment: `a.name` and `b.name` are not defined in your first query, so that will not run.

Comment: You want a `sum(value)` not a `count()`, right? What is `a` and `b` tables here? I suspect that much of the issue whatever join you aren't sharing here.

Comment: SELECT ..., SUM(...) ... GROU...

Comment: @GordonLinoff It was a mistake from my first formulation.

Comment: On a side note: Why `COUNT(0)`? `COUNT(<expression>)` is especially made to count non-null occurrences of an expression. If you want to count rows, just use `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to aggregate your rows and get one result row per name. This translates to `GROUP BY name` in SQL. For counting use `COUNT` and inside use `CASE WHEN` to decide what to count.

```
select name, count(case when value > 0 then 1 end)
from mytable
group by name
order by name;
```

This works because `COUNT` only counts non-null occurences. We could just as well use `SUM`  for counting: `sum(case when value > 0 then 1 else 0 end)`.

In your example there is only 0 and 1. If these are the only possible values, you can just add them up:

```
select name, sum(value)
from mytable
group by name
order by name;
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want aggregation? The following query would actually produce the correct results for your sample data:

```
select name, sum(value) sum_value
from mytable
group by name
```

Comment: I forgot about `sum`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name, count(*)*(case when sum(a.value) >= 1 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM table a 
GROUP BY name;
```

For a better solution, give more details about the nature of the value column

Comment: `value` has two values: 1 or 0. P.S.: My `where` was a mistake. I changed it.